# What is an ideal TFS ALM Environment Setup for a Solo Developer?

Tags: tfs

I am a solo developer evaluating TFS 2012 for source control, build management and testing of a client server application. I am especially excited about its Lab Management features which allow me to manually or automatically test my application against different environments. After reading the documentation, however, I am left more confused.

It seems as if I will have to deploy several physical or virtual host machines just to use it. I want to avoid the hassle of maintaining extra machines if I don't have to. Assuming I have the following development machine:

- 16GB RAM
- i7 Quad Core Processor
- 1TB HD drive
- 1 128GB SSD drive

What is the ideal setup for TFS ALM 2012 for a solo developer where physical or virtual host machines are minimized and performance is least compromised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hardware resources are limited I would recommend you look at [TFS service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/), it will give you all of the benefits without having to support the hardware. The other good part is the service seems to be updated more frequently and being as Lab Management is relatively new that may end up being a real help.

Comment: Note: TFS Service doesn't currently support lab management

Comment: Really, so the testing it supports in the documentation is all just the manual test case execution? That's dissapointing.

Comment: You can still use test controllers/agents to do automated testing by manually setting up virtual machines as standard environments. You just can't automatically provision new virtual machines based off templates.